# Custom Field Not Updating on Post Save WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written up a function to take a few custom taxonomies & post title in this case (street (post title), city, state, zip) and geocode them into a lat/long to be saved into a custom field `_ct_latlng`.

The problem is its not firing on post save or update. Any help is appreciated!

```
function ct_geocode_address($post_id) {
    global $post;
    if($_POST['post_type'] != 'listings')
        return;

    $city =  wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'city');
    $city = $city[0];
    $city = $city->name;
    $state =  wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'state');
    $state = $state[0];
    $state = $state->name;
    $zip =  wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'zipcode');
    $zip = $zip[0];
    $zip = $zip->name;
    $street = get_the_title($post_id);

    if($street && $city) {
        global $post;
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($street.' '.$city.', '.$state.' '.$zip)."&sensor=false";
        $resp = wp_remote_get($url);
        if ( 200 == $resp['response']['code'] ) {
            $body = $resp['body'];
            $data = json_decode($body);
            if($data->status=="OK"){
                $latitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                $longitude = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
                print $latitude.','.$longitude;
                update_post_meta($post_id, "_ct_latlng", $latitude.','.$longitude);
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'ct_geocode_address');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if($_POST['post_type'] != 'listings')
```

with

```
$post = get_post( $post_id );
if($post->post_type != 'listings')
```

UPDATE:

The problem is that you are running your `ct_geocode_address` function on the default priority of 10.

You have code elsewhere in the theme that updates the values manually entered into the listing's meta box. The values manually entered are overwriting the value set via ct_geocode_address(). This means that the field is saving, but then it's saving again based on the $_POST value sent from edit.php.

Change

```
add_action('save_post', 'ct_geocode_address');
```

to

```
add_action('save_post', 'ct_geocode_address', 999);
```

That will work.

Comment: Tried, same result doesn't fill the custom field with lat/long on update or new post.

Comment: Are you updating the post through the standard edit screen or via wp_update_post()?

Comment: Can you confirm that your save function is firing at all?

Comment: What would be the best way to test that?

Comment: Quick and dirty method is to add a `die('1');` to your code. IF the screen goes blank and shows a 1, it worked.

Comment: It definitely fired, I get the lat/long on save/update, here's a screenshot: http://grab.by/vi2e

Comment: Its just not updating the _ct_latlng custom field

Comment: Check the database manually right after saving. My suspicion is that it is actually saving but your meta box that displays the value is not displaying it correctly, giving it the appearance of not saving.

Comment: Can you post a more complete example that also includes the meta fields? I'll be happy to test it and debug directly.

Comment: Sent you a DM on Twitter with the theme & XML

Comment: Okay I've found the problem. Your code was working fine, it was just getting overwritten. Answer edited above to show solution.

Comment: If that worked, could you please select this as the working answer?

Answer (score 0):

Custom post type slugs tend to be singular - perhaps it's just a typo tripping you up?  Try testing against `listing` (singular) rather than `listings` (plural).  Of course, this just depends on how you've defined the CPT.

Also, try using the [get_post_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) function to test against.

`if( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'listing' )`

Comment: Thanks but its definitely listings.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lan = $latitude.','.$longitude;
update_post_meta($post_id, "_ct_latlng", $lan);
```

Comment: No go, unfortunately.